# JQuery - Add POST variables to a href link

Tags: jquery

In a table I have links like this: `test.php?id=1`

I want to pass `prev_id` and `next_id` to test.php as well. (Purpose of these variables is create next/prev buttons; the list can be sorted by the user so no easy way to find out inside test.php.)

However, I do not want `prev_id` and `next_id` to be visible in the URL for the user. Can I format the href like this:

```
<a href="test.php?id=1" prev_id="5" next_id="45">
```

and use JQuery to "hijack" the link, keeping id as GET in the URL, but sending `prev_id` and `next_id` to test.php as POST?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is your code:

```
 <a id="link" href="test.php?id=1" prev_id="5" next_id="45">
```

and the jquery code

```
$("a#link").click(function(){

    $.post("test.php",
       {
         prev_id: $(this).attr("prev_id"),
         next_id: $(this).attr("next_id")
       },
       function(data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
       }
    );

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi, the correct info get passed to the page after changing `"test.php"` to `$(this).attr("href")`.

But I want the click to *go to* the actual page, not to display it in an alert box! What to do?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change 'href' attribute.My callback function is only example. You can do what do you want.

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery post

call a function to post your data by onClick event,

```
 <a onClick="postdata()" prev_id="5" next_id="45">
```

and the jquery code

```
function postdata(){
    $.post("test.php", { id: "1", next_id: "2" },
       function(data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
       });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this won't keep id as a visible GET variable, and does not degrade gracefully as well?

Comment: @elaxsj, Instead of `$.post` use `$.get` to make the _GET_. Just keep in mind that the actual operation is made hidden, the browser will not change at all unless you program it to. [JQuery get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've found to do this kind of thing is to dynamically add a form to your page then submit it:

```
$('body').append('<form id="myawesomeform"></form>');
$('#myawesomeform').attr('action','test.php?id=1');
$('#myawesomeform').attr('method','post"');
$('#myawesomeform').append('<input type="hidden" name="prev_id" id="prev_id" value="5">');
$('#myawesomeform').append('<input type="hidden" name="next_id" id="next_id" value="45">')
$('#myawesomeform').submit();
```